# Are there resources that explore interchange between object and the subject caused by a verb?

Tags: terminology, historical-linguistics, linguistic-typology, comparative-linguistics

1. Are there linguistics terms that describe the following phonemenon?

2. I desire to learn the possible explanations or reasons that in English, certain verbs interchanged the subject and object to express the same meaning, whereas in other languages, the cognate verbs did not experience such change. Examples:

1. The English verbs ['like'](http://www.etymonline.com/index.php?allowed_in_frame=0&search=like&searchmode=none) and ['please'](http://www.etymonline.com/index.php?allowed_in_frame=0&search=please&searchmode=none) originally required the object before the subject, as French and Spanish still require. What might have caused the inversion in English?

[Gustar algo a alquien](http://www.wordreference.com/es/en/translation.asp?spen=gustar) literally translates to 'something likes, to someone'.

2. English and Spanish verbs express longing from the subject's perspective, but French from the object's. What might explain this difference? For example:

Spanish: [Echo de menos](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/echar_de_menos) a algo/alquno.
French: Quelqu'un ou quelque chose me manque.

Comment: Notice that _like_ and _please_ are both predicates of emotional status. You'll find that these verbs often have different configurations. _Please_, for instance, occurs either as stative or causative: _I am pleased with that, That pleases me._ _Like_ in Middle English had a dative subject (like _think_ and _seem_): _This likes me not; Methinks she doth protest too much; Meseems it is too difficult._ Now _think_ has an experiencer subject, and _seem_ is a flip verb that takes A-Raising. Things change over the centuries.

Answer (score 1):

Haspelmath (see here for a reference [Subtypes of Standard Average European](https://linguistics.stackexchange.com/questions/20919/subtypes-of-standard-average-european/20939#20939)) calls this *Nominative experiencer* for your English example and *Dative experiencer* for your Spanish example. There are studies of the frequency of the types of experiencer, including the study on Standard Average European by Haspelmath.